# Can't access network PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I have 3 Win 7 computers network together in a joined homegroup. PC A host the homegroup. PC B & C join the homegroup. Each PC has no problem accessing each other file sharing. Until recently, I renamed PC C to D. The problem is now PC B has problem accessing PC D, but PC D can access to PC B. When PC B try to access PC D, it will popup a dialog box requesting entering username & password. However, PC A still can access to PC D.

Why is that after renaming, that PC cannot be accessed by other PC? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ive had this problem with homegroups but it may have been on XP. What fixed it for me was removing PC D from the homegroup

1. Open HomeGroup by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, typing homegroup in the search box, and then clicking HomeGroup.
2. Click Leave the homegroup
3. Click Leave the homegroup, and then click Finish. (it is twice)
4. Reboot

Then add the PC to the homegroup and you should be back to where you were before the rename.

The reason for the problems is in `PeerNetworking`

Also try this:

1. Click **Start**
2. Open **Control Panel**
3. Open **Network and Sharing Center**
4. Click **Choose homegroup and sharing options**
5. Click **Change advanced sharing settings**
6. Scroll down to **Password Protected Sharing** and turn it off

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried, but seems doesn't help to solve the problem.

Comment: @user1995781 I've updated the answer with another step top try